# Problema de conexion de Netbeans 12 y github con windows 10

Tags: netbeans, git, apache, github, windows10

Tengo un problema con apache netbeans a la hora de hacer push por https a github. Le introduzco el nombre de usuario y contraseña correcta pero no me hace el push. Me responde:

https://xxxxxxx%40gmail.com@github.com/xxxxxx/prueba3.git: not authorized

El caso que si puedo clonar desde github Desktop.He estado leyendo y he eliminado las credenciales de windows de git. En el archivo de configuracion c:\users\xxx.git creo que esta bien:

```html
[user]
    name = xxxxxx
    email = xxxxxx@gmail.com
[filter "lfs"]
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
    process = git-lfs filter-process
    required = truecir el código aquí
```

La verdad ya no se que tocar. ¿Alguna idea donde prodía estar el error? Gracias

Comment: hasta lo mejor de mi conocimiento, github ahora no permite hacer autenticación con user/password. Hay que usar tokens

Comment: Gracias eftshift0  lo probe y salio bien todo a la primera. Ya me funciona, la verdad que llevaba tiempo sin usarlo.